# Concatenate str

Tags: python

I have a main class that returns the result of a secondary class. The problem is defined in the following message in the terminal:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "CompletedProcess") to str

This is due to the sub-process that I need to concatenate within the body of the html, below is an excerpt from the primary class and the secondary class:

Primary Class

```
def do_GET(self):
    self.do_HEAD()
    from index import Index
    o_html = Index().view()
    self.wfile.write(bytes(o_html, "utf8"))
    return
```

Secondary Class

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3.9
import subprocess

# Class name : Index -> Structure html page :
class Index:

    # Class method : Constructor -> Object Build :
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # Class method : build ->  : Render code html :
    def view(self):

        self.v_shell = subprocess.run("ls")
        # Variable : v_html5 -> Code Html
        self.v_html5 = """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="pt-BR">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Webstrucs Action</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Action</h1>
                Python Web Server For Asynchronous Requests<br>
                """ + self.v_shell + """
                <p>
                </p>
            </body>
            </html>
        """
        return self.v_html5
```

How can I get around this TypeError?

Comment: `self.v_shell = subprocess.run("ls", capture_ouput=True).stdout` you need to capture it and access using `stdout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the shell output of `ls` and you can get that by running `subprocess.getoutput("ls")` instead of `subprocess.run("ls")`.

Answer (score 0):

`self.v_shell` is a `CompletedProcess`. To get its result as text, you need to capture the output and access it as `stdout`.

```
self.v_shell = subprocess.run("ls", capture_ouput=True).stdout
```

Then you can concatenate that in your string.

Comment: the call must be made with `capture_output=True` parameter for this to work, as in my comment

Comment: Right. If you write this as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you want to implement a web console and you are returning the result of your shell command, from the error message you get I can say probably you forgot to get the result of "ls" command and concatenate the casted result (to string of course), instead you are trying to concatenate the information of how the process went.
for instance, the ls command returns the following as its intended result:

```
folder1 folder2 folder3
```

and this message that the process ran successfully:

```
code(0) successfull
```

or something like that and you are trying to concatenate the successful process object instead of list of folders.